# Python searching for image in wrong directory

Tags: python, file, filenotfounderror

I am trying to load some assets onto my program that I have them in a folder called 'Graphics', which is inside the folder 'Snake', which is inside the folder 'Projects', which is inside the folder 'Python'. However, also inside that folder 'Python' is another folder named 'HelloWorld'.

I am trying to load some assets in a program that I am running in 'Snake' and Python is searching for the assets in the 'HelloWorld' folder (which is where I used to keep my python files).

I get the error:

`FileNotFoundError: No file 'Projects/Snake/Graphics/apple.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\35192\OneDrive - WC\Desktop\Python\HelloWorld'`

I believe that for this I have to change the default directory for vs code. I have changed the default directory for the command prompt and it did nothing. Perhaps this is because the python that I am running in the command prompt is different from the one in vs code (?)

How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
This is how I am currently loading the image:
`apple = pygame.image.load('Projects\Snake\Graphics\apple.png').convert_alpha()`

Comment: In your question you often use the term "Files", but since the description doesn't make sense as it is I think you mean "Folders". Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Matthias yeah that is correct im sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to construct the path to your images. You wil have to add `import pathlib` to your code.

`pathlib.Path(__file__)` will give you the path to the current file. `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent` will give you the folder. Now you can construct the path with the `/` operator.

Try the following code and check the output.

```
import pathlib

print(pathlib.Path(__file__))
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'Grahics' / 'apple.png')
```

Now you will be able to move the full project to a totally different folder without having to adjust any code.

---

Your code example looks like this: `apple = pygame.image.load('Projects\Snake\Graphics\apple.png').convert_alpha()`

If you import `pathlib` you can replace that with the dynamic approach:

```
path_to_image= pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'Grahics' / 'apple.png'
apple = pygame.image.load(path_to_image).convert_alpha()
```

I'm quite sure that pygame can work with a path from pathlib. If not then you have to convert the path to a string manually

```
apple = pygame.image.load(str(path_to_image)).convert_alpha()
```

Comment: How should I write it when I import the assets?

Comment: How do you load them now? Please add the code to the question because it will be unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work tho. I got the error: ```pygame.error: No video mode has been set```

Comment: That's a different error and has nothing to do with the path. In fact it shows that the image can be found but the setup of pygame isn't complete. A simple [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) before loading the images and after `pygame.init()` might be enough.

Comment: I solved it. Basically I had set the mode after I imported the image and I should've done so afterwards. Thank you! have a good day

Comment: I didn't use pygame for several years, but I'm glad I remembered something from the old days. And concerning the "good day": in my location midnight is coming closer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the default directory. Just load from the full directory. That should look something like: "C:\Users\...\Python\Snake\Graphics\apple.png".

Comment: I got a syntaxerror: ```SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape```

Comment: `\U` starts a unicode escape sequence. You either have to use a raw string (`r"C:\Users\..."`) or double the backslashes to escape them or use forward slashes (yes, that works even on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to first see your active directory by simply typing in
`pwd`, and then you could simply change the directory by `cd("C:/path/to/location")`,  remember you have to use the backslash, or just use the following library:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/path/to/location")
```

As pydragon posted, you could also import it by just giving the import function a path.

Comment: I try to avoid changing a global state from a program  if I don't need to.

Comment: `os.chdir `changes the current working directory of the python process executing it. Once you exit the python process and return to the shell process that spawned it. the working directory of that process won't be affected. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right. But what would happen if everybody would use `os.chdir` and rely on the result? Imagine what happens if you import 3 modules and each of those modules tries to set the current working directory to a different path. The last one will win and the others don't use the correct folder anymore. `os.chdir` seems to be an easy and simple solution, but it will give you hell.